# Basic DNS query via UDP and python

Tags: python, dns, udp

In this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/173187/what-does-a-dns-request-look-like there is an example UDP packet that can be used to query a DNS server for the address of `www.google.com`.

I wrote a basic Python snippet:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

raw = "24 1a 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 77  77 77 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01  00 01"
hex = raw.split()

ints = [int(i, 16) for i in hex]
bytes = [chr(i) for i in ints]

packet = "".join(bytes)
s.sendto(packet, ("8.8.8.8", 53))

s.recvfrom(1024)
```

But nothing happens. I get no response. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Shouldn't I receive an UDP packet on the same port with the answer to my query?

Comment: What is the actual contents (DNS request) you're sending? The bytes sequence from the answer in serverfault question is a hex dump of the binary request shown by Wireshark. Sending those exact values is different than sending the DNS request.

Comment: Oh. Is it? I took those hex values, starting from 24 1a, converted them in a sequence of bytes (hex to int then chr) and joined them into a string. Then I sent the string. Is this different than sending a request? How? What am I missing?

Comment: @farzad I edited my question to include the code that generates the actual packet. Am I doing something wrong here?